# How can I solo the quest Redemption?

Tags: dungeons-and-dragons-online

I just made a Paladin in Dungeons and Dragons Online.  I'm currently playing through the first few quests outside of Korthos, and I am currently stuck on "Redemption".  I soloed several equivalent encounters with ease, but I have repeatedly failed at this one when after meeting Heyton I am forced to defend him from several waves of Sahuagin.  I'm never threatened, but even with Intimidate I can't keep him from being killed.  I've tried healing him with "Lay On Hands" but I can't seem to target him, and always waste the "Lay On Hands" on myself.

How can I complete this quest *solo*?

Comment: I've completed it solo on Normal diff with a Monk, a Rogue and a Ranger so I'm guessing there's something you're doing wrong at some point. Never tried a Pally, though, so not sure I can really tell what.

Comment: Yes, please give us more information. Character name and server so we can look up your build on MyDDO.  Character level and class are also useful for those that do not want to look up the build.  What part in particular are you getting stuck on?

Comment: I'd recommend the named items from collaborator. Those should help you kill them faster as they give bonus damage to monstrous humanoids, including sahuagin.

Comment: @ShoeMaker I'd recommend NOT adding character level and build information; the idea is to provide answers that help multiple users, not just the person asking the question.

Answer (score 6):

The best way to win this is to hire the cleric hireling in town. Summon her when you first enter the dungeon and set her on passive (to save her mana). When you get to Heyton spot, move all the way to the back of the room first (She gets stuck behind the ice floor, but teleports to you if you go to the back of the room). Set her to assist and just before the fight starts, target Heyton and set her to interact with him. She will heal him while you fight.

I have yet to figure out how to heal him directly, but she does this just fine.

Comment: Bringing a hire makes the quest no longer technically completed ''solo'', but is good advice if you just want to get it done.

Comment: You'd have to be very pedantic to treat having a hireling as not 'solo'

Comment: No need to leave the cleric at the entrance. Just visit the shrines just before visiting Heyton. When you target the shrine and press the 'interact' (6th) button on the hireling bar, she will sit down and regenerate her spellpoints.

Answer (score 3):

First off, good on you for being  a Pally!

Secondly, to target someone/thing, right click them. Your "target array/panel/thing" will now display them even if your cursor is not on them, and you can now cast spells on them. With my 14 CHA at Lv 2 I healed Heyton for about 24 HP with my 1/day Lay On Hands.

What I had:

```
 +1 Power Plate
 Lightning Greataxe
 Boots of +2 Intimidate and +2 Diplo
 Other Random Gear
```

What I did:

I ran forward, as far as I could go (literally walking in place with my head nearish the middle of the barrier). When the first wave spawned, I waited for them to choose their targets as my Axe flails about bringing a couple low, then Intimidated them to me, then QUICKLY tripped the largest one (because a caster was not in this wave for me; those are top priority) and then smacked them each once in a row until they all died (to maintain the intimidate, which, IIRC (from playing 3.5) requires the intimidated to be damaged or they'll stop being intimidated). Rinse, repeat.

TL;DR

```
1: walk in place on the barrier
2: Intimidate all enemies
3: damage each of them once really quickly
3b: Trip the Caster *OR* the Largest one (in that order)
4: Kill them all
5: Rinse, Repeat
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

First, I recommend a good read about [how intimidate works](http://ddowiki.com/page/Intimidate).  Secondly, you would need a good CHArisma score to use that to keep Heyton healed because this is the stat that the amount of healing granted from you [Lay on Hands](http://ddowiki.com/page/Lay_On_Hands) is based on.  Third, if I remember correctly, the waves are mixed types of [Sahuagin](http://ddowiki.com/page/Sahuagin), I usually target the casters first, they tend to have the highest DPS.

Comment: maybe add that Sahuagin are monstrous humanoids and that you just happen to receive a weapon against those from the collaborator quest.